# Fine grained access control with cognito identity and custom claims

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-iam-policy

I have a cognito identity pool that assigns a principal tag named `home`. I create credentials with [fromCognitoIdentityPool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-credential-providers/Variable/fromCognitoIdentityPool) (which ultimately calls [AssumeRoleWithIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html) ).

Further, I use these credentials to invoke a lambda named `locate` which has the following policy for allowing access to only items with primary key same as the value of `home`:

```
        - Statement:
            - Action: [dynamodb:GetItem]
              Effect: Allow
              Resource: !Sub "arn:${AWS::Partition}:dynamodb:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:table/${PlacesTableName}"
              Condition:
                ForAllValues:StringEquals:
                  dynamodb:LeadingKeys:
                    - "${aws:PrincipalTag/home}"
```

However, this condition always fails and I get access denied exception:

```
AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::...:assumed-role/...-UserRole-.../Locate is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:GetItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:...:table/Places because no identity-based policy allows the dynamodb:GetItem action
```

Any ideas?